# Materialize intermediate checkbox state

Tags: checkbox, materialize

How do I get a checkbox to show as "indeterminate" when unchecked in Materialize ?

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" checked/>
<label for="test" id="test-label">Red</label>
```

JS:

```
$('#test-label').click(function() {
    var checkbox = $(this).prev();
    if (!$(checkbox).is(':checked'))
        $(checkbox).prop('indeterminate', true);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhwkfb75/8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `indeterminate` instead of `intermediate`. You probably got confused due to their similar spellings.

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).prop('indeterminate', true);
});
```

Comment: That's right ! I didn't know you could just apply it to the checkbox, I thought you had to apply it to the label. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Two things are important to achieve this:

1. Prevent the default handler
2. When setting the indeterminate state, you also have to disable the checked state, otherwise though the checkbox appears as intermediate, `$(chk).prop('checked')` will still be `true`.

Hello

```
$('#check-label').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var chk = $("#test");

    if ($(chk).prop( "checked" )) {
        $(chk).prop( "indeterminate" , true );
        $(chk).prop( "checked" , false );
    } else {
        $(chk).prop( "checked" , true );
        $(chk).prop( "indeterminate" , false );
    }

});
```

or even more elegant:

```
$('#check-label').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var chk = $("#test");

    $(chk).prop("checked", !$(chk).prop("checked"));
    $(chk).prop("indeterminate", !$(chk).prop("checked"));

});
```

See the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhwkfb75/16/).